# pass value as argument from js to play controller

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to pass value of js to controller but it can not detect as argument.
 [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fYU0.png)

My code is like:

```
  var v1 =e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

   var url = "@routes.HomeController.dropDown(v1)";
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please add your js code as well. Or please check what is the value of v1. Try to print the value and check

Comment: I printed value and it is working.

Comment: I try to pass String value to controller.

Answer (score 0):

`v1` is only available at runtime. So all you can do is to create a static path with `@routes.HomeController.dropDown()` for example > `/api/home/dropdown`

`route` file would have

`GET     /api/home/dropdown    controllers.HomeController.dropDown()`

It will work to have a 2. entry like:

`GET     /api/home/dropdown/:value    controllers.HomeController.dropDown(value)`

So in your JS Code it looks like:

`var url = "@routes.HomeController.dropDown" + "/" + v1;`

I never used `@routes...` for just path resolution - but this should work.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried but not worked it says that You can make this conversion explicit by writing `dropDown _` or `dropDown(_)` instead of `dropDown`.